# Missing images on a Bootstrap template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with the template here:

http://demo.onokumus.com/metis/v12/

I got all the source from github:

https://github.com/onokumus/Bootstrap-Admin-Template

For some reason, all of the icons are missing. [image]

I triple checked the folders to make sure everything is there. The email icon is using icon-envelope style inside bootstrap.min.css.

```
 .icon-envelope{background-position:-72px 0}
```

I do have this image: background-image:("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the relative path

Comment: Paths are correct. I even included the full URL for the images, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons are an actual font (not image) called font awesome: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/
The path for this font can be seen in "font-awesome.min.css"

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.0');
src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.0') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.0') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.0') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: That explains why I am seeing F086 instead of an icon. The css link is  href="assets/Font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css". The css file is there, so I am not sure why I am still having this issue.

Comment: And the font folder is there?

Comment: Not the css…the actual fonts: font/fontawesome-webfont.eot